# How to manage lifecycle in a ViewGroup-derived class?

Tags: android

I had a bunch of code in an activity that displays a running graph of some external data. As the activity code was getting kind of cluttered, I decided to extract this code and create a `GraphView` class:

```
public class GraphView extends LinearLayout {
    public GraphView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        inflater.inflate(R.layout.graph_view, this, true);
    }

    public void start() {
        // Perform initialization (bindings, timers, etc) here
    }

    public void stop() {
        // Unbind, destroy timers, yadda yadda
    }
        .
        .
        .
}
```

Moving stuff into this new `LinearLayout`-derived class was simple. But there was some lifecycle management code associated with creating and destroying timers and event listeners used by this graph (I didn't want this thing polling in the background if the activity was paused, for example).

Coming from a MS Windows background, I kind of expected to find overridable `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` methods or something similar, but I haven't found anything of the sort in LinearLayout (or any of its inherited members). Having to leave all of this initialization code in the Activity, and then having to pass it into the view seemed like it defeated the original purpose of encapsulating all of this code into a reusable view.

I ended up adding two additional public methods to my view: `start()` and `stop()`. I make these calls from the activity's `onResume()` and `onPause()` methods respectively.

This seems to work, but it feels like I'm using duct tape here. Does anyone know how this is typically done? I feel like I'm missing something...

Comment: Today I asked to myself the same question! :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You may be able to get some use out of overriding `protected void onAttachedToWindow()` and `protected void onDetachedFromWindow()`  I have never tried, but they may be called approximately when you would like.

Answer (score 6):

I've only done a brief experiment with this, but it appears that if you override `onAttachedToWindow` and `onDetachedFromWindow` as mentioned by CaseyB above along with overriding

`protected void onWindowVisibilityChanged(int visibility)`

It should give you the information you need.

I'm running into the same situation as you. I'm surprised there is no notification mechanism for this.

Answer (score 3):

**Unfortunately, View object does not have any callbacks methods as the Activity when going from background and active mode.**

Anyway, if you insist on such an approach, I guess the closest you get is to put the init code  into the constructor and the destruct code into an override of finalize(). Though, the finalize() method is runned by the system when the object is not referred to anymore, making it ready to be garbage collected. It may not be called at all if vm exits. And I would not recommend this way.

**Also, you don't want to create and destroy the GraphView object(s) over and over again when your app goes from pause to resume as short lived objects causes memoryleaks.** You never know when the gc will free memory for these objects, even there is no references to them.

I think your approrach with start() and stop() methods are ok, just keep them simple and clean. All they got to do is to maintain the AsyncTasks (or Timer objects).

*(Off-topic regarding the way you inflate your views: I use View.inflate() mostly as it saves me for a few lines of code)*